# How to show a facebook themed dialog box with custom message in IFrame mode?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to show a dialog box using javascript, just like using alert() but the dialog box should have a facebook theme/style.

I am doing it in Facebook IFrame mode.

Must I use FBML mode to show facebook style dialog?

Thanks.

Wilson

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/

Not sure what IFrame mode is, but this should at least give you some of the styling.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Using FB.ui under iframe mode can make use of dialog in FBML.